# Eclipse won't save settings and data

Tags: eclipse

My problem is weird and I think simple to solve but I can't find a solution for this!

Eclipse won't save the settings I set. For example, the options "Save before build" and "Save dirty editors before build" are selected but for some reason Eclipse won't save before the build. If I change something in the file I have to save the file manually with "cmd + s" in order to see a change after the build.

Also, the color theme always jumps back to some weird colorful theme (after every restart of eclipse) I did not select eventhough my theme is selected when I open up the preferences.

Does anyone what's going one? Seems like Eclipse has trouble overwriting it's own config files or something. I don't know... but it's really annoying.

Comment: Which Eclipse would be this? Did you recently upgrade the IDE, while using an older workspace?

Comment: Seems like this was the problem. I used Eclipse Luna, but now Mars. I just reinstalled Eclipse Mars again and now it works. I changed nothing and imported my gradle projet but this time everything saves properly. I don't know why.

Comment: If I were you, I'd use a fresh install of Luna, because Mars isn't officially released.